# linear algebra: projecting a line past a known point by a known distance

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, projection

I know this shouldn't be too difficult, but, unfortunately, I have forgotten a lot.

Have `2` known points, the distance between those `2` points, and the distance of the line I would like to know the end point of. That is, I want to project past the known end point the differential distance and determine this point.

For example, I have `(665306, 1520215)`, `(665578 1520167)`, and desired distance `~372`. The distance between the two points is `~276`.

How would I extend past `(665578 1520167)` `96 = 372 - 276` on the same path and determine that point?

I was looking at projections but this was reliant on a second vector that will allow us to project from vector 2 to vector 1 a perpendicular vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll label the point $(655306, 1520215)$ as $A$ and the other as $B$. We want to find the point $C$ on the line $AB$ such that $AC = 372$ and $BC = 96$. To do this, we first find the vector $AB$ by subtracting the two points, and then multiply the vector $AB$ by $\frac{372}{276}$. This gives us vector $AC$, and we now add this back to $A$ to find $C$.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will give it go and see that it works out.